# $3\times 3$ matrix with eigenvalues are given

Tags: matrices

> If $P=\begin{bmatrix}
> 0 & -2 & 3\\ 
>  -1&  1& -1\\ 
> a & 2 & b
> \end{bmatrix}$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{R},$ suppose $1$ and $2$ are eigenvalues of $P$ and $P\begin{bmatrix}
>  1\\ 
>  0\\ 
> -3
> \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
>  3\\ 
>  0\\ 
> -3
> \end{bmatrix}$. Then $P^4\begin{bmatrix}
>  1\\ 
>  -1\\ 
> 0
> \end{bmatrix} =$

**My Try::** Here $$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2 & 3\\ 
 -1&  1& -1\\ 
a & 2 & b
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 1\\ 
 0\\ 
-3
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
 3\\ 
 0\\ 
-3
\end{bmatrix}$$
After multiplication we get $$\begin{bmatrix}
 3\\ 
 1\\ 
a-b
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 3\\ 
 1\\ 
-3
\end{bmatrix}$$

So we get $a-3b=-3$.

Now, how can I solve it after that? Help is required. Thanks.

Comment: How is $P(1,0,-3)^t=(3,0,-3)^t$? Specifically, $(-1)1+1\cdot 0+(-1)(-3)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\operatorname{tr}(P)=\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3;$$
$$b+1=1+2+\lambda_3\implies\lambda_3=b-2.$$
$$\det(P)=\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3;$$
$$-a-2b-6=2(b-2)\implies a+4b=-2.$$
On the other hand,
$$a-3b=-3$$
if
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2 & 3\\ 
 -1&  1& -1\\ 
a & 2 & b
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 1\\ 
 0\\ 
-3
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
 -9\\ 
 2\\ 
-3
\end{bmatrix} \begin{matrix} \\ \\ . \end{matrix}$$

Comment: Thanks Behrouz Maleki, Would you like to explain me first $4$ lines,

Comment: Please, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{\lambda }_{i}}}=tr(P)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{a}_{ii}}}\,\,\, , \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}{{{\lambda }_{i}}}=\det (P)$